# Create Graph in excel using Apache

Tags: excel, apache

i have a code. i want to create a graph using database entries. i have created graph but in that graph , values of x and y axises are not shown. plz help me . Thanx in advance.Here is my code

```
{
   // Drawing drawing = spreadsheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
   // ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 8,10,20,25);
   // Chart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
   //ScatterChartData data = chart.getChartDataFactory().createScatterChartData();
   //ValueAxis bottomAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxisAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
   //ValueAxis leftAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
   //leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
   //ChartDataSource<String> xs = DataSources.fromStringCellRange(spreadsheet, new CellRangeAddress(2, NUM_OF_ROWS-1, 1, 1));
   //ChartDataSource<Number> ys1 = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(spreadsheet, new CellRangeAddress(2, NUM_OF_ROWS-1, 2, 2));
   // ChartDataSource<String> xs1=null;
   // ChartDataSource<Number> ys2=null;
   //data.fillChart(chart,bottomAxis);
   //data.addSerie(xs, ys1);
   //data.addSerie(xs1, ys2);      
   //ScatterChartSerie chartSerie = data.addSerie(xs, ys1);
   //chartSerie.getXValues();
   //chart.plot(data, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
   //FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newFile("C:\\Users\\ranig\\programs\\data1.xls"));
   //workbook.write(out);
   //out.close();
   //System.out.println("SCLD.xlsx written successfully");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved this problem myself. I forgot a jar file. when I add that jar file , my problem was solved.
Thanks